# IBM Connections Atom Profile Service

Tags: ibm-connections

I am trying to get back a profile for myself but I only get back a successful http response...no data.  This is the code I am using.

```
try {

    RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://apps.na.collabserv.com","my.email","my.password");

    Response<AtomFeed> responseFeed = restClient.doGet("/profiles/atom/profileService.do").asAtomFeed();

    System.out.println(responseFeed.getData().toXmlString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I try to add a email= to the url I get a 403 forbidden return.

Not really sure what the issue is,

Thanks!

Comment: try the API in your browser.  The SBT is working as it should as that URL is protected, and you cannot query via the parameter email.  you can use the userid, which can be retrieved via typeahead.

Comment: The call will work if I don't have email....which is fine.  I am using it to do authentication from a SPA and Restful backend.  I do not get any information back in the profile data though.  Why would there be no profile data?

Comment: right - email is blocked/disabled in the environment.  you can get the profileService doc, and then parse it to get the profileEntry or UUID for the logged in user